# Translate origin of rotation matrix

Tags: rotational-matrices

I'm applying rotation matrix on Stewart platform joints to get their position referenced to basement.

Code used is here:

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
  float mx = baseRadius*cos(radians(baseAngles[i]));
  float my = baseRadius*sin(radians(baseAngles[i]));
  baseJoint[i] = new PVector(mx, my, 0);
}

for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
 float mx = platformRadius*cos(radians(platformAngles[i]));
 float my = platformRadius*sin(radians(platformAngles[i]));

  platformJoint[i] = new PVector(mx, my, 0);
  q[i] = new PVector(0, 0, 0);
  l[i] = new PVector(0, 0, 0);
  A[i] = new PVector(0, 0, 0);
}

for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
  // rotation
  q[i].x = cos(rotation.z)*cos(rotation.y)*platformJoint[i].x +
    (-sin(rotation.z)*cos(rotation.x)+cos(rotation.z)*sin(rotation.y)*sin(rotation.x))*platformJoint[i].y +
    (sin(rotation.z)*sin(rotation.x)+cos(rotation.z)*sin(rotation.y)*cos(rotation.x))*platformJoint[i].z;

  q[i].y = sin(rotation.z)*cos(rotation.y)*platformJoint[i].x +
    (cos(rotation.z)*cos(rotation.x)+sin(rotation.z)*sin(rotation.y)*sin(rotation.x))*platformJoint[i].y +
    (-cos(rotation.z)*sin(rotation.x)+sin(rotation.z)*sin(rotation.y)*cos(rotation.x))*platformJoint[i].z;

  q[i].z = -sin(rotation.y)*platformJoint[i].x +
    cos(rotation.y)*sin(rotation.x)*platformJoint[i].y +
    cos(rotation.y)*cos(rotation.x)*platformJoint[i].z;

  // translation
  q[i].add(PVector.add(translation, initialHeight));
  l[i] = PVector.sub(q[i], baseJoint[i]);
```

Each point it's correctly initialized providing their positions by angle. Providing a rotation vector, I've as result a rotated platform based on It's center.

What I'd like to do, is to perform a rotation on arbitrary point (distant x,y,z from platform center) that I provide.

I've thought about 2 methods:

- Geometric calculation of each joint respect to a provided point (complex if It's also not on same level). Apply this calculations also on base to have their center perpendicular.
- Apply an additional rotation matrix translated by a vector

I'd like a tip about which way is correct (computationally light) or If there's already known way to move rotational center of this points.